# The rank of the elliptic curve $E(m):y^2 + xy - my = x^3 - mx^2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E(m)$ denote the elliptic curve
$$
E(m):y^2 + xy  - my = x^3 - mx^2.
$$
Are the smallest values of $m$ such that $E(m)(\mathbb Q)$ has rank 3 (and 4) known?

Comment: @Wojowu For instance for $m=46$ I get the following with Sage version 8.0 


sage: E = EllipticCurve([1,-46,-46,0,0])

sage: E.rank()

1

sage: E.gens()

[(12903/196 : 777699/2744 : 1)]

Comment: Ah, silly me, I've misread the form of the elliptic form. Thanks for pointing that out, Jesper.

Comment: A new calculation confirms Henri's results: $m=3877,4921$ are the two lowest $m$ for which the rank is $3$.

Answer (score 4):

The smallest rank 3 occurs for m = 3877 (I do not understand the comment: for
m=46 the rank is 1 for instance).

Comment: That was my bad, I've misread the question - I was certain it says m,-m in place of -m,-m.

Comment: In fact, this is interesting: the points [0,0] and [0,m] are on both curves (-m,-m) and (m,-m), but they are of order 4 on (-m,-m) and of infinite order on (m,-m): this explains why rank 3 occurs so much more frequently on (m,-m) than on (-m,-m)